# Elasticsearch DSL Filter

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am having a problem with the elastic-search filter. I am trying to search for a text using elastic-search DSL filter, but I am facing issue with sorting.

Search text: **hello world**

Other string in the document: **Hello there, hello world, hello everyone, hi hello**, etc...

Elasticsearch-dsl query is:

```
MyDocument.search().filter(Q("match", title="hello world") | Q("match", original_title="hello world")).execute()
```

Elasticsearch query is like this:

```
{
    'bool': {
        'filter': [{
            'bool': {
                'should': [{
                    'match': {
                        'title': 'hello world'
                    }
                }, {
                    'match': {
                        'original_title': 'hello world'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

The output is like **hello everyone, hi hello, hello world**, etc..

but I want **hello world** first.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query, it appears that you would want to search the same token/tokens from multiple fields.

Of course @jaspreet mentioned the answer you want, but if you would want to simplify your query(of course [Bool Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) are also quite simple), then you can make use of [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) as below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["title", "original_title"], 
      "query": "hello world",
      "default_operator": "OR"
    }
  }
}
```

You could also make use of [multi-match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query to simplify your query as below:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "hello world",
            "fields": ["title", "original_title"],
            "operator": "OR"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In both use-cases, you would get the desired result.

Of course you would need to test it out and see how response appears and what use-cases you can possible solve using these.

**Note:** Just an additional note based on @Val's comment, you can also make use of [simple query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html#query-dsl-simple-query-string-query) instead of `query_string` if the input is something that comes from the user, which unlike `query_string` does not throw any errors for invalid syntax.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also worth noting that if the search strings are input by users it's better to use [`simple_query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) instead of `query_string` as it will not throw errors in case of bad search syntax

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are using "filter"

> The filter parameter indicates filter context. Its match clauses are used in filter context. They will filter out documents which do not match, but they will not affect the score for matching documents

If you will check _score in returned hits, it will be zero

Replace your query with

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title": "hello world"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "original_title": "hello world"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**"hello world"** will get higher score than **"hello everyone, hi hello, hello world"**
shorter fields get higher score than longer ones in elastic search.